# Spring boot activemq using pooledConnectionFactory not working

Tags: spring, activemq-classic

I am developing on Spring boot activemq, using `pooledConnectionFactory`, already set `spring.activemq.pool.enabled=true` in `application.properties`.

I already created a `PooledConnectionFactory`,  but what value shall be input after this setting : `spring.activemq.pool.configuration.*`. It is really confusing.

Comment: Show your code.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! If possible, please provide a [minimum, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  For more tips on asking a good question (ie. one which will be answered faster), see the [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page.

Comment: Welcome to SO. As the other comments suggest, we can only help you, if you give us some context, i.e. show us your code. Please use the edit function to add your code and indent it by four sapces so that it renders correctly. Additionally, I took the liberty to reformat your question so that the code bits you provided are formatted properly.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the Spring Boot Version you may need the dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.messaginghub</groupId>
    <artifactId>pooled-jms</artifactId>
</dependency>
```